# Why do they walk into the Haunted Forest carrying weapons?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wizard-of-oz

In [**The Wizard of Oz**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032138/), right after the group leave the Wizard's Castle to begin their quest to retrieve the witched broom, they enter the haunted forest... carrying weapons!

- Scarecrow: a gun
- Lion: a net and bug sprayer
- Tin Man: a pipe wrench

Where did they get them? (it isn't explained or shown)

Oz doesn't seem to be the type of place where these should be readily available... especially a gun.

Also, why does the Tin Man need a *pipe wrench*, when he's already carrying an axe?

Comment: Bug spray and wrenches and *guns*? Oh my! (sorry, I couldn't resist)

Comment: The section of the movie that's in color _is_ a dream, and things in dreams don't always make sense....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Some of it is explained](http://www.kansascity.com/entertainment/wizard-of-oz/article1206582.html):

> In the original script (by Noel Langley, Florence Ryerson and Edgar Allan Woolf) there’s no mention of a gun. The ax is explicitly referenced. **The bug spray and net are left over from a previous musical number called “The Jitterbug” that was shot but cut in the editing room.** (The song — with such lyrics as, “Oh, the bats and the bees and the breeze in the trees have a terrible, horrible buzz” — was an attempt to capitalize on the dance fad.)

There is even some rehearsal footage for this scene:

However:

> Pistols, revolvers, sidearms, six-shooters — nothing. Someone made a conscious decision during production that the Scarecrow should pack heat.

To be frank, there are [numerous issues with the film](http://www.debunkingmandelaeffects.com/the-scarecrow-has-a-gun/):

> The production, restoration, and continuity of the film is a mess. [The Movie Mistakes website entry for The Wizard of Oz](http://www.moviemistakes.com/film1418/pageall) has 22 pages of errors (which features this “Mandela Effect” funnily enough). This scene appearing in the movie with inexplicable items is not out of the realm of possibilities.